# MouseEvents inside JList objects

Tags: java, swing, location, mouseevent, jlist

I am a bit confused regarding a situation I have. I created a ListModel extending DefaultListModel and ListRenderer implementing ListCellRenderer for displaying a custom cell in a JList. The cells are some objects created from a class extending JPanel, that contain a JLabel and a JButton.

My issue is related to the mouse events: I want to trigger a certain event when clicking on the JButton inside a cell of the JList, yet I can not figure out how to match the mouse source point to that of the JButton from the respective index. More exactly, I added a mouse listener to the list, but I want it to trigger something if the mouse point is located inside the bounds of the JButton, and another action if it's on the data item. I added some prints to find out the cause of this, but before that some code to highlight the structure:

```
 public WifiGuiHandler(JButton reference) {
    btnReference = reference;
    wifiListener = new WifiListener();
    wifiPopupContainer = new JScrollPopupMenu("Connections.");
    wifiPopupContainer.setMaximumVisibleRows(7);
    connectionsHolder = new ArrayList<>();
    listOfConnections = new JList();
    listOfConnectionsModel = new ListModel(connectionsHolder);
    listOfConnectionsRenderer = new ListRenderer();
    listOfConnections.setModel(listOfConnectionsModel);
    listOfConnections.setCellRenderer(listOfConnectionsRenderer);
    wifiPopupContainer.add(listOfConnections);
    wifiPopupContainer.pack();
    initializeTestVariables();
    initializeListeners();
}
```

Here, the constructor for the class that takes a JButton and adds a mouse listener to it, that triggers the appearance of a JPopupMenu, which has only one component, the JList that hold the entire data. Also, links the ArrayList with the data items to the ListModel.

```
public void initializeTestVariables() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
        WifiItem item = new WifiItem("Connection number " + i + ".", i);
        connectionsHolder.add(item);
    }
}
```

Setting up the data items.

```
public void initializeListeners() {

    listOfConnections.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            int index = listOfConnections.locationToIndex(e.getPoint());
            if (index >= 0) {
                WifiItem item = (WifiItem) ((ListModel) listOfConnections.getModel()).getElementAt(index);
                System.out.println("Button of " + item.getConnectionName() + " is at location :" + item.getButton().getLocation());
                System.out.println("Button has the bounds : " + item.getButton().getBounds());
                System.out.println("MouseEvent detected on : " + e.getPoint().getLocation());
                if (item.getButton().getBounds().contains(e.getPoint())) {
                    item.connectHere();
                }
                if (item.getButton().isVisible()) {
                    System.out.println("Set expanded on : " + item.getConnectionName());
                    item.setExpandedState(false);
                    listOfConnectionsModel.fireContentsChanged(item, index, index);
                    updateGui(false);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Set expanded on : " + item.getConnectionName());
                    listOfConnectionsModel.fireContentsChanged(item, index, index);
                    item.setExpandedState(true);
                    updateGui(false);
                }
            }
        }

    });
    btnReference.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            updateGui(true);
        }
    });

}
```

And this is where the confusion arises. I correctly get the data item( WifiItem) from the mouse event location/point, but when I click on the JButton of the WifiItem, it doesn't trigger that method, like it doesn't seem to detect that the JButton actually is there. I also set up the prints, and what is strange, the Point for the JButton is always the same, even though it actually is different, and this seems to be the problem. More exactly, from the output of the program:

> Button of Connection number 2. is at location :java.awt.Point[x=137,y=33]
>
> Button has the bounds : java.awt.Rectangle[x=137,y=33,width=90,height=26]
>
> MouseEvent detected on : java.awt.Point[x=172,y=125]
>
> Button of Connection number 3. is at location :java.awt.Point[x=137,y=33]
>
> Button has the bounds : java.awt.Rectangle[x=137,y=33,width=90,height=26]
>
> MouseEvent detected on : java.awt.Point[x=172,y=125]

The above mouse events points were actually located on the JButton itself, only it didn't get that. As another strange fact, only if I click the JButton of the FIRST element of the list does it trigger the required mouse action.

Another print revealed that all the JButtons have the same Point and Rectangle, and I don't get it. There are 10 items in the JList, each displayed properly, how can all their JButtons have the same location? I must be missing some key element here. I looked at other posts and tried other recommendations: converting the point with SwingUtilities, removing all the mouse listeners from the JList and adding them to the data items.

To sum it up,the issue is that the list triggers the events for the correct data item in it(meaning, I do get the correct index for the item located there), but if the mouse event happens on the JButton of any data item inside the list, it doesn't trigger the required effect (the point is not withing the bounds of the button, even though it should be).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> More exactly, I added a mouse listener for the list, but I want it to trigger something if the mouse point is located inside the bounds of the JButton, and another action if it's on the data item.

An easier solution would be to use a `JTable`. The data is separated into columns and the `JTable` has an API to let you know which row/column was selected.

You can use the [Table Button Column](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) as your renderer/editor for the button.

Edit:

> only if I click the JButton of the FIRST element of the list does it trigger the required mouse action

Sounds like your conversion of the mouse point is off.

> , how can all their JButtons have the same location?

Again, the button location is releative to the renderer panel. The panel itself is relative to the row in the JList. So I would guess you need to need the row index and add the height of each of the previous rows to your calculation.

Comment: I will try to switch to JTable tomorrow, I first considered using it but I don't want my data to be separated in the columns, since in my data item class(WifiItem), the button is aligned below the label that displays the text, for design purposes (as suggested by team members). Also, as seen in the code, when you click on of the items, it will 'minimize' (hides the button and resizes so it only shows the label) or 'maximize' (shows the button and expands its size). Thanks for the suggestion, anyway, I will try tomorrow and come back with a result.

Comment: @g0dzax, `the button is aligned below the label that displays the text,` - JTable won't work for that. See edit for additional comments.

Comment: The idea with the height added to the calculation is brilliant. I will try it.

Comment: So, I set up a method to calculate the height of previous rows and for the row at index(k), it also calculates the distance between the button and the top of the panel, and when the user clicks on a row > 0, it will set the rectangle that contains the button to the default X(since x is never changed), and sets it's Y to the calculated height, after which it performs the check. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @g0dzax, Glad it worked. `JList` has a `getCellBounds(...)` method to get your the Rectangle of a given row. From there you should just need to adjust the x/y values by a fixed amount.